# jQuery: contains() always returning true

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a parent jQuery object and a child jQuery element.
I'd like to see if the child is already contained within the parent. I was thinking of using jQuery's `contains()` method. However, in Chrome and IE I always get `true` returned and in FF6 I get an error `a.compareDocumentPosition is not a function`

Am I using this incorrectly? Is there a better way to achieve this?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ColdToast/Njvbg/3/)

Code:

```
<div class="metroContainer">
<div class="metroBigContainer">
    <div id="big1" class="metroBig">
        Stuffs 1
    </div>

    <div id="big2" class="metroBig">
        Stuffs 2
    </div>
</div>

<div class="otherContainer">
</div>
```

```
// I expect false, returns true
$.contains($('.metroBigContainer'), $('.otherContainer'))
```

Comment: I think it may be because `contains()` takes a DOM element, and what you are passing it is a jQuery object.

Comment: I do not see a closing </div> for metroContainer. Maybe that is causing jquery to become confused about which div is contained within the other divs

Comment: @dave I believe the browser uses a 'stack' model for assigning closing div tags to opening tags; that is, a closing tag closes the most recent open tag. In other words, metroContainer would contain everything, and the actual DOM structure would match the clear intent in this case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe contains takes dom elements, not jquery objects:

```
$.contains($('.metroBigContainer')[0], $('.otherContainer')[0])
```

Comment: :( You are right. I was assuming because its a jQuery fnc, it would take jQuery objects... Funny thing is I actually turned it into a jq obj specifically for that purpose :)

Answer (score 2):

also you could try testing the length

```
$('.metroBigContainer .otherContainer').length
```

if it is 1 (or greater then 1) then it exists if not then it doesn't exist.